# Selecting records in SQL based on another table's contents

Tags: sql

I'm a bit new to SQL and have trouble constructing a select statement. I have two tables:

```
Table users
    int id
    varchar name

Table properties
    int userID
    int property
```

and I want all user records which have a certain property. Is there a way to get them in one SQL call or do I need to first get all userIDs from the properties table and then select each user individually?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If there's only one property row per user you want to select on, I think this is what you want:

```
 select
     users.*
 from
     users,
     properties
 where
     users.id = properties.userID
     and properties.property = (whatnot);
```

If you have multiple property rows matching "whatnot" and you only want one, depending your database system, you either want a left join or a distinct clause.

Comment: Steve, do not learn this outdated syntax. Learn to use explicit joins instead.

Answer (score 15):

Use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT U.id, U.name, P.property FROM users U
INNER JOIN properties P ON P.userID = U.id
WHERE property = 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp) command.  You could write a query like the following:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    users u
    INNER JOIN properties p
        ON u.id = p.userID
WHERE
    p.property = <some value>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT [Name] FROM Users u 
JOIN Properties p on p.UserID=u.ID
WHERE p.Property=1
```

Obviously it depends what flavour of RDBMS and TSQL you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking to `JOIN` tables.

Assuming the id and userID columns have the same meaning, it's like this:

```
select u.name
from users u inner join properties p
on u.id = p.userID
where p.property = :ValueToFind
```