# How to JOIN 2 SELECT statements but only show output when conditions from table A are met on table B

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-workbench

I'm practicing views and I need to JOIN two tables, (the easiest way) but on table A I have like 6 rows when conditions are met, and on table B with the same conditions regarding table B (same column name), like 82.

I need to show only the data regarding those 6 rows.

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS 
SELECT Name AS Country, Population FROM country WHERE Population >= 9000000;
SELECT District, Name AS City, Population FROM city WHERE Population >= 9000000;
```

Im working with the world database.

```
_________________City_________________

ID | Name | CountryCode | District | Population

_________________Country_________________

Name | Population | Code
```

Sample data:

City

[image]

Country

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a column in the table Country like code or countrycode?

Comment: True. There's two, Code and Code 2.

Comment: Then edit your question and also post sample data and expected results to clarify your requirement.

Comment: Note that queries against views in MySQL have limited access to underlying indexes, rendering them (in my view) rather useless

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting records in SQL based on another table's contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703297/selecting-records-in-sql-based-on-another-tables-contents)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a view that join the two table you could  use

```
    CREATE VIEW myview AS 
    SELECT co.Name AS Country
        , co.Population Country_population
        , ci.District 
        , ci.Name As city
        , ci.population City_population
    FROM country co 
    INNER JOIN city ci ON  ci.CountryCode = co.Code 
    WHERE ci.population >= 9000000
```

then

```
 select * from myview;
```

Comment: This looks promising, but there's a syntax error near INNER JOIN that I don't quite catch, besides the missing 'p' in population i mean.

Comment: Ok, now it works, but it shows to many rows, Im guessing I could just limit the output, but I think the idea is too only show the data from city, so probabily only need to use Population  from City, i guess.

Comment: answer updated adding conditiion for city too  .. if you want you can remove the condition for country population

Comment: Awesome, removed the condition and now it works great. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From your expected results I assume that you want for each country the city/cities with `population >= 9000000`, so join like this:

```
select 
  c.Name country,
  t.district,
  t.city,
  t.population
from country c inner join city t 
on t.countrycode = c.Code 
where t.population >= 9000000;
```

You don't need to set the condition `population >= 9000000` for the country too because a country with a city with `population >= 9000000` surely satisfies that condition.